# Returning first 3 values in a array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, arc4random

I have a array that looks like this:

```
var myArray = ["1one", "1two", "1three", "1four", "1five", "1six"]
```

And to get random, I use this:

```
var originalNames = [String]()

func getRandomName() -> String {
    if (names.count == 0) {
        names = originalNames
    }
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(names.count)))
    return names.removeAtIndex(randomNumber)
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
self.randomLabel.text = getRandomName()
```

As you can see, the array contains six different strings. The code that I am currently using, will return add the strings inside the array at random, but I only want to return the first 3 strings randomly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using

```
var originalNames = [String]()

func getRandomName() -> String {
    if (names.count == 0) {
        names = originalNames
    }
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    return names[randomNumber]
}
```

so `let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))` this will return random `Int` value upto 3.

Comment: @RoduckNickes this will never pick any of the last 3 elements from the array at the first draw

Comment: @RoduckNickes this method may also return the same element more than once

Comment: What if i want to return the first 3 string, but not return the same string with repetition?

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = ["1one", "1two", "1three", "1four", "1five", "1six"]
var result:[String] = []
while result.count < 3 {
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray.count)))
    result.append(myArray.removeAtIndex(randomNumber))
}
print(result)   // "["1two", "1one", "1three"]\n"
```

if you don't want to modify the original array just make a copy of it

```
let myArray = ["1one", "1two", "1three", "1four", "1five", "1six"]
var inputNames = myArray
var result:[String] = []
while result.count < 3 {
    result.append(inputNames.removeAtIndex(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(inputNames.count)))))
}
print(result)   // "["1six", "1two", "1one"]\n"
```

Comment: @RoduckNickes what do you mean ? You need to show some more code if you don't know where to place it

Comment: All i have is a view controller with classname, `viewDidLoad`, `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and `buttonAction`.

Comment: you are only getting one element at a time

Comment: When using `self.randomLabel.text! = result`, i get error: `Cannot assign a value of type String to type String.`

Comment: you can access the first element of your array using ----->    result.first ?? "default string or empty string"

Comment: the second just result[1] and so on

Comment: Your code it wrong. I got result `1six` 2 times in a row, and also the 4th time. When using `result.first`.

Comment: you should get the result elements in order

Comment: All you need it is a counter as index to pick the correct element. don't generate your result array more than once